# How To Press <CTRL>

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pywinauto

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application.start("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\EXCEL.exe")
app.Microsoft_Excel.TypeKeys('%a')
```

%a = <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

I Want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>. is there a sign for this?

Comment: That's not going to work. `$a` is not valid Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use <kbd>Control</kbd> key specifier - `^`, so try:

```
app.Microsoft_Excel.TypeKeys('^a')
```

You can get documentation on SendKeys mini-syntax [here](http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/) or [here](http://00010xg.wcomhost.com/rjp3/rjp3help/sendkeys_reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

U can use:     send_keys('^a')