# How to get the current URL from Chrome using pywinauto 0.6

Tags: google-chrome, url, pywinauto

In this question [How can I get a url from Chrome by Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475103/how-can-i-get-a-url-from-chrome-by-python), it was brought up that you could grab the url from python in pywinauto 0.6. How is it done?

Comment: Good question. Thanks for heads up. But need some time to prepare code snippet workable without typing keys and mouse clicks. Did you try something on your side? Already learnt the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)?

Comment: No, sorry. I used copy and clipboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Chrome tab URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675506/get-chrome-tab-url-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Using inspect.exe (which is mentioned in [Getting Started](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#gui-objects-inspection-spy-tools)) you can find Chrome's address bar element, and that its parameter "value" contains the current url.

I found two ways to get this url:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pywinauto import Desktop

chrome_window = Desktop(backend="uia").window(class_name_re='Chrome')
address_bar_wrapper = chrome_window['Google Chrome'].main.Edit.wrapper_object()
```

Here's the first way:

```
url_1 = address_bar_wrapper.legacy_properties()['Value']
```

Here's the second:

```
url_2 = address_bar_wrapper.iface_value.CurrentValue

print(url_1)
print(url_2)
```

Also if protocol is "http" Chrome removes "http://" prefix. U can add sth like:

```
def format_url(url):
    if url and not url.startswith("https://"): 
        return "http://" + url
    return url
```

Comment: Can we get a update on this? Doesn't work on new chrome versions