# How do I get the current active tab in google chrome, using python

Tags: python, google-chrome

I am trying to get the current Tab URL the user is in. I was referring to similar question on SO [Previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645123/how-do-i-get-the-url-of-the-active-google-chrome-tab-in-windows) but both first and second answers are no longer working as you can't really access elements of Chrome window using win32gui anymore

Maybe there is a way to take the latest URL from the History file stored in the pc..

> Please make sure the answer works for Chrome latest version with Python 3.x

Comment: ty for pointing that out, edited

Comment: Try this - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261802/275751

Comment: I am using Google Chrome, the above answer is for FireFox.

Comment: If you scroll up and see the question , the OP asks about chrome. so bascially you need to create a directory in that path. Try it alteast.

Comment: I'm not sure how. I need the equivalent file for Chrome He uses the firefox one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Chrome tab URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675506/get-chrome-tab-url-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You may consider usink *keys* / *hotkeys*.

### Selecting

**F6** - acces your url for focused active tab

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(0, 200) # a random click for focusing the browser
pyautogui.press('f6')
```

**CTRL** + **TAB** - next tab

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab')
```

**CTRL** + **SHIFT** + **TAB** - previous tab

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'tab')
```

**ALT** + **TAB** - for another chrome window ( usefull if you know you are only chrome opened)

pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')

**CTRL** + **T** - open new tab

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 't')

**CTRL** + **W** - close curent tab

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'w')

### Copying

For **copy the url**, you can use either pyperclip...

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c') # for copying the selected url
import pyperclip # pip install pyperclip required
url = pyperclip.paste()
print(url)
```

either clipboard module...

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c') # for copying the selected url
import clipboard # pip install clipboard required
url = clipboard.paste()
print(url)
```

More about hotkeys into : [documentation1](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/internet-explorer-tips/how-to-switch-between-tabs-in-ie7-using-shortcut-key/), [documentation2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475103/how-can-i-get-a-url-from-chrome-by-python#answer-35479163)

PS: I have Chrome x78.0 on windows 64 bit os, and it's working for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
o = sh.tail(sh.grep(sh.cat("/home/user/.config/google- 
chrome/Default/Sessions/Session_somelatestfile"), "-a", "-Eo", " 
(http|https)://[^/']+"), "-1")
print(o)
```